# COUNTIFS returns incorrect result when applied to the output of QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In [my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3A4bw2e-IC9a8KZtynFECPhyW1-Syv_xMhBTudU1o8/edit#gid=1836993182&vpid=A1) the chart for Negative Feedback weekly pulls data from the `Query` sheet, but the logic doesn't work to separates negative feedback from positive feedback.  The logic works fine on the non-queried tab `Responses`. Specifically, the command:

```
=Countifs(Responses!$B$2:$B$500, "221*", Responses!$E$2:$E$500, "<>"&"")
```

correctly returns `3`, but:

```
=Countifs(Query!$B$2:$B$500, "221*", Query!$E$2:$E$500, "<>"&"")
```

returns `5` even though the data is the same. `Query` sheet is the result of applying QUERY to `Responses`.

There are five rows where B matches wildcard pattern `221*`, but for two of them the column E is empty. The second criterion (nonempty cell in E) does not appear to work when applied to this output of QUERY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting some strange behavior of Sheets, quite possibly a bug. I will first describe a way to reproduce it, and then a way to avoid it.

#### To reproduce:

Put some text in cells A1 and A3, leaving A2 blank. In cell B1, enter `=query(A1:A3, "select *")`. The content of cells B1:B3 will now *appear* to be identical to A1:A3.

But B2 is **not really blank**. Specifically:

- `=isblank(B2)` returns FALSE, while `=isblank(A2)` is TRUE
- `=istext(B2)` returns TRUE, while `=istext(A2)` is FALSE
- `=counta(B1:B3)` returns 3, while `=counta(A1:A3)` is 2.
- `=countif(B1:B3, "<>")` returns 3, while `=countif(A1:A3, "<>")` is 2.

### To avoid

Don't use countif or counta on the results of `query` (at least until this bug is fixed). As an alternative, use `filter` command to apply the criteria, and then `counta` to count the (nonempty) results. Thus, instead of

```
=Countifs(Query!$B$2:$B$500, "221*", Query!$E$2:$E$500, "<>")
```

use

```
=counta(filter(Query!$B$2:$B$500, regexmatch(Query!$B$2:$B$500, "^221")*len(Query!$E$2:$E$500)))
```

which is admittedly more complex but gets correct results. There are two filter criteria, which are imposed as logical AND by multiplication:

- column B entry matches the regular expression `^221`  (equivalent to wildcard pattern 221*)
- column E entry has positive length -- this is a robust check that is not affected by the strange behavior of `query`.

Since in the filtered results, the column B is guaranteed to be nonempty,  `counta` will return the number of all rows that match the filter.

---

An alternative, slightly shorter formula with the same result:

```
=sum(arrayformula(regexmatch(Query!$B$2:$B$500, "^221")*(len(Query!$E$2:$E$500)>0)))
```

This evaluates the two criteria as True/False, coerces them to 0-1 integers by multiplication, and sums the results.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a clone of the column(s) you want to do the `COUNTIFS`/`SUMIFS` function on off to the right of the query result columns and hide either the query result columns or the cloned results.  For example, say you want to take column B that has query results in it and execute a `SUMIFS` or `COUNTIFS` on column B, go into the first empty column on the right (call it column Z), and in Z2 enter the formula `'=B2'` and drag that formula through the rest of Z cells.  Then execute your `COUNTIFS` or `SUMIFS` on column Z.